# Showing that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $U$ (or $W$ or both)

Tags: vector-spaces

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ and we have two subspaces, $U$ and $W$, then how do I properly define that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $U$ (or $W$). I know that this is a subspace of $V$ and can define this well but I'm not sure how to show that they're subspaces of $U$ and $W$ clearly. My issue is not being clear with the notation and I'm unsure of how to go about this.

Comment: If you just try to wing it with the best (but not perfect) notation you can come up with, what do you get?

Comment: Well I known how to test for subspaces using the test of checking for the zero vector, closure under scalar multiplication and closure under addition but this would show that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $V$. So I would possibly consider saying the $U$ and $W$ are vector spaces themselves and try defining something like that but it seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Let's start by looking at the definition of "subspace". I don't know exactly how it's phrased in your textbook, but usually it would go something like:

> Suppose $(A,f,g)$ is a vector space (with $f:A\times A\to A$ being the vector addition and $g:\mathbb R\times A\to A$ being the scalar multiplication). To say that $B$ is a **subspace** of $A$ means that
>
> 1. $B$ is a subset of $A$,
> 2. $0\in B$,
> 3. For all $x,y\in B$ it holds that $f(x,y) \in B$, and
> 4. For all $c\in \mathbb R$ and $x\in B$ it holds that $g(c,x)\in B$.

If we apply this definition to find what it means for $U\cap W$ to be a subspace of $(U,\oplus,\odot)$, we get

> Suppose $(U,\oplus,\odot)$ is a vector space. To say that $U\cap W$ is a **subspace** of $U$ means that
>
> 1. $U\cap W$ is a subset of $U$,
> 2. $0\in U\cap W$,
> 3. For all $x,y\in U\cap W$ it holds that $x\oplus y \in U\cap W$, and
> 4. For all $c\in \mathbb R$ and $x\in U\cap W$ it holds that $c\odot x \in U\cap W$.

Now the first of these three conditions is a simple matter of set algebra.

The other three conditions are *exactly the same* conditions as you needed to show for knowing that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $(V,\oplus,\odot)$. You can therefore **either** reuse that part of your earlier proof word for word, **or** simply point to the fact that you know that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $(V,\oplus,\odot)$, which *means* (among other things) that those two conditions are true.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x,y)\in B?$

Comment: @user258521: aagh, yes, of course. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks ! The first condition wasn't very clear to me before asking the question although it seems quite obvious now

Answer (score 1):

First note that $U \cap W$ must contain at least the zero vector since they are both vector subspaces which by definiton means they include the zero vector.

Now assume there is a vector lets call $v$ such that $v \in U \cap W$. This means that $v \in U \space \& v \in W$. Since the vector $v$ is in the vector space $U$ and $W$ defined over the field $F$ then $\forall c \in F$ the vector $cv \in U \space \& \space cv \in W$. Therefore $cv \in U \cap W \space \forall c \in F$ which means the set $U \cap W$ is closed under scalar multiplication by an element in $F$.

Now assumes there are $2$ vectors lets call $v_1, v_2 \in U \cap W$. This means that $v_1,v_2 \in U \space \& v_1,v_2 \in  W$. Since $U$ and $W$ are vector subspaces themselves that must mean they are closed under addition so $v_1 + v_2  \in U \space \& \space v_1 + v_2  \in W$. Therefore $v_1 + v_2 \in U \cap W$ and the set $U \cap W$ is closed under addition.

This shows that $U \cap W$ is a subspace of both $U$ and $W$. Note: notice how it did not matter whether or not $U$ and $W$ where subspaces of another vector space, the  criterion for them was to be defined over same field $F.$

Comment: I still see this as the test for checking whether something is a subspace of a vectorspace V? Could you expand on your last point about the criterion, I think that is what I'm missing

Comment: You can instead define $U$ and $W$ not as subspaces of another vector space $V$ but instead just define them as any vectorspaces over some field $F$ and the proof is still valid. In other words, not once did i use the fact that a vector $v$ should be included in $V$ just used it to be included $U$ and $W$ since it existed in their intersection.

Comment: Yes that was what I was unsure about, having parallel vector spaces but I think it's more clear now !